# Multiple Conditons in ternary operator React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-operator

Hello Guys I have two conditions working with the ternary operator in javascript.

Here is my code it basically tells a button to be disabled or enabled:

```
disabled={(props.isAllowedState && (props.zkub == " " || props.zkub == "B")) || (!props.zkub == " " || !props.zkub == "B") ? false : true}
```

I also tried it this way:

```
disabled={(props.isAllowedState && (props.zkub == " " || props.zkub == "B")) ? false : (!props.zkub == " " || !props.zkub == "B") ? false : true}
```

But it does not work, when I take the conditions seperatly and test both of them it works but together they dont.

Maybe someone can give me a hint on how to solve this.

Faded

Edit: My If approach

```
  const checkDisableButton = () => {                                                 
    if(props.isAllowedState && (props.zkub == " " || props.zkub == "B")) {
      return false 
    } if (!props.zkub == " " || !props.zkub == "B") {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  };
```

The call:

```
disabled={() => checkDisableButton()}
```

Comment: An `if statement` would be much more readable.

Comment: Why are you assigning boolean conditions truth values? you can just set this up as one condition without `true` and `false`

Comment: @Andy yeah I also tried that but my result was not the one I expected - maybe I did it wrong tho so if you could show me your approach I would look into it - I will edit my question and show my if Function

Comment: @rm-fme what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @yesIamFaded, Let me understand the reuirement:  if isAllowedState == true and  zkub is empty or equal to B it will return  False?

Comment: @RajshekharYadav yes thats correct

Comment: @Andy your comment made me laugh haha

Comment: @yesIamFaded if you want to return `False` when `(props.isAllowedState && (props.zkub == " " || props.zkub == "B")) || (!props.zkub == " " || !props.zkub == "B") `  is True, then just put `!` before it instead of using a ternary operator or a function:

`!props.isAllowedState && (props.zkub == " " || props.zkub == "B")) || (!props.zkub == " " || !props.zkub == "B")`

Comment: @yesIamFaded Can you please share the code which is working and where you apply condition separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an `isDisabled` function that uses an if statement rather than a complicated ternary.

```
function isDisabled() {

  const { isAllowedState, zkub } = props;

  if (isAllowedState && (zkub === ' ' || zkub === 'B')) return false;
  if (zkub !== ' ' || zkub !== 'B') return false;
  return true;

}
```

Then call it:

```
disabled={isDisabled()}
```